# How do I enable web3 in Coinbase wallet?

Tags: web3js, dapp-development

I am building a very simple dapp.  At first I want to initiate web3 on the webpage and then enable it so that I can access web3.eth.getAccounts().

MetaMask, and Opera Mobile both have a window.ethereum.enable() function which will prompt the user to allow the webpage to access the wallet. Once they do that, I can call web3.eth.getAccounts, like this:

```
    ethereum.enable().then(() => {
        web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
          console.log(accounts)
        })
      })
    }
```

Coinbase Wallet (aka Toshi) doesn't have window.ethereum.enable, (or equivalent) so I can't access getAccounts()

Anyone know how to get it to work?

Comment: I'd suggest to try some of the workarounds from the old MetaMask documentation https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/detecting_metamask.md, ie for example `web3.currentProvider`.

Comment: That still doesn't shed any light on how to enable / unlock the user's wallet in order to make transactions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that in Coinbase Wallet, web3 is enabled by default, so you just have to do:

```
    web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
      console.log(accounts)
    })
```

...and you don't need to call `ethereum.enable` first.  I'm they will probably change this though, as it's a security concern (all sites visited using that browser will be able to see your address).